# Imageview in android using base64 string retrieved from firebase

Tags: java, android, imageview, firebase

```
     int i=0;
  ArrayList<String> list;
        queryRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

                    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChild) {
                        Map<String, Object> value = (Map<String, Object>) snapshot.getValue();
                        String name1 = String.valueOf(value.get("Base64String"));
         **list = new ArrayList<String>();
                        list.add(name1);**
                        System.out.println("Base64 " + i++ +" "+ name1 );
                **System.out.println("1 "+list.toString());**

                    }
```

This listener each time getting the value and printing eg : in below output i value is incremented till all value fetches from firebase.

**Output in console:**

```
Base64 0    basfbjksdvkjvskjvbskdj
1           basfbjksdvkjvskjvbskdj
Base64 1    dvfjovbfdjbsklcnsalcks
1           dvfjovbfdjbsklcnsalcks
Base64 2    dvbjsvfbvjksdkvbsdvjkb
1           dvbjsvfbvjksdkvbsdvjkb
Base64 3    qdncwe98yfecbsdjcksbdv
1           qdncwe98yfecbsdjcksbdv
```

I have to use this base64 String and display image. below is the code for displaying base64 string as a image if there is a single base64 string. Problem is String name1 changes each time it retrieves , so have to change the imageview after putting first base64 string. I don't know how to move to another imageview before getting next base64 string from firebase.

**Code for imageview using firebase base64 String**

```
byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(name1.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT); 
image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0,imageAsBytes.length) );
```

if i use the above code , because of each time values changes in the name1 it is not working. how can i do this.

**EDITED:**

This is the link which I am referring
http://www.androidinterview.com/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/

this link contains

```
String[] itemname ={
            "Safari",
            "Camera",
            "Global",
            "FireFox",
            "UC Browser",
            "Android Folder",
            "VLC Player",
            "Cold War"
        };

    Integer[] imgid={
            R.drawable.pic1,
            R.drawable.pic2,
            R.drawable.pic3,
            R.drawable.pic4,
            R.drawable.pic5,
            R.drawable.pic6,
            R.drawable.pic7,
            R.drawable.pic8,
    };
```

for the above input i have to replace my inputs. BUT my images are in base64 string but example is using Interger array. how can i do this.

Below is code it stores base64 string in list and name of employee in list1

```
  name1 = String.valueOf(value.get("Path"));
                    name2 = String.valueOf(value.get("Name"));

                    list.add( name1);
                    list1.add(name2);
```

Below code I stored list values in String array then bundled these to send ,to use input for displaying name and picture of employee instead of **itemname and imgid.**

```
        spath = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
        sname = list1.toArray(new String[list1.size()]);
        Bundle bundle =new Bundle();
        bundle.putStringArray("names",sname);
        bundle.putStringArray("paths",spath);
        Intent ilist = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MActivity.class); 
        startActivity(ilist);
```

Extraxted data:

```
String itemname[]=bundle.getStringArray("names");
    String abcd[]=bundle.getStringArray("paths");
```

Comment: whether you are trying to show those images in listview or trying to show it in already created imageviews

Comment: @vishwa already created imageview

Comment: if there is possibility to solve this issue using listview, tell me how can i do that

Comment: i need some clarifications whether you confirm received base64 string from firebase is static i mean interms of count

Comment: I am registering employee by getting their name ,phone no and taking employee picture, it will be sent to firebase for storage, image is storing as base64 string. There is a option called View Employees in android app, if that option is clicked all the employee pictures (i.e) base64 string of images have to retrieve  from firebase display as image like a gallery. The count will vary when new employee added.

Comment: Create an ArrayList and store name1 string to it.after getting all response show the arraylist in listview or gridview using adapter(pass the arraylist).

Comment: `ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
       list.add(name1);` I have done like this  can you see my above post i have edited code and output

Comment: Now how can I use this **list** out side that listener. Did i used the arraylist correctly this is what you mean ?

Comment: @vishwa When i print list out of the listener only 1 value is printing, each time it get value and storing by replacing the already existing value.

Comment: list = new ArrayList<String>(); decalre it outside the listener

Comment: because whenever the listener literates it creates new Arraylist so that you are getting single value only.

Comment: ya thank you so much , nw i got all values printed. how can I use `list` to display as images? If possible give me some snippet of it please

Comment: Create adapter and set pass this arraylist as source within getView finction convert base64 as bitmap and show it in image.finally set adapter to listview or gridview.For creating adapter try this.http://www.pcsalt.com/android/listview-using-baseadapter-android/

Comment: @ vishwa Thank you . I am not clear how to use these adapter, getView all .. i try to do

Comment: if you need help on implementing adapter pls let me know

Comment: @vishwa in edited i added my doubts can you able to see and help me

Comment: can you give me some example code to display an array of base64 string as an image in listview or already created imageview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try  this one...

In first Activity Create CustomArrayList instead of ArrayList string.So that you no need to save name in another arraylist ..

```
     ArrayList<ListCustomObjects> datas;
```

After oncreate initialize this.

```
     datas=new ArrayList<ListCustomObjects>();
```

Put this code inside your **queryRef.addChildEventListener**

```
   ListCustomObjects objects=new ListCustomObjects();
    //you can change to original data
    String name1="Data";
    String name2="Datas";
    objects.setName(name1);
    objects.setPath(name2);
    //add the custom objects to arraylist
    datas.add(objects);
```

In first activity  Button onclick put this code...

```
   Intent secondIntent=new Intent(CustomArrayList.this,SecondArrayList.class);
           Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
           //inorder to send custom arraylist from one activity to another activity we need to use either parcelable or serializable.here am using parcelable for beter performance..
            bundle.putParcelableArrayList("List",datas);
            secondIntent.putExtra("Bundle",bundle);
            startActivity(secondIntent);
```

In second Activty put this code...

```
    ListView listview=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView2);
    Bundle bundle=getIntent().getBundleExtra("Bundle");
    ArrayList<ListCustomObjects> datas=bundle.getParcelableArrayList("List");
    SecondArrayListAdapter adapter=new SecondArrayListAdapter(SecondArrayList.this,datas);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and create a class file as **ListCustomObjects** for ArrayList custom objects

```
public class ListCustomObjects implements Parcelable{


String name;
String path;

public ListCustomObjects() {

}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPath() {
    return path;
}

public void setPath(String path) {
    this.path = path;
}

public ListCustomObjects(Parcel in) {
    name = in.readString();
    path= in.readString();

}


@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(name);
    dest.writeString(path);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<ListCustomObjects> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<ListCustomObjects>() {
    public ListCustomObjects createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new ListCustomObjects(in);
    }

    public ListCustomObjects[] newArray(int size) {
        return new ListCustomObjects[size];

    }
};

}
```

and create adapter name as **SecondArrayListAdapter**.Here am using base adapter.

```
public class SecondArrayListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

ArrayList<ListCustomObjects> datas;
Context context;


public SecondArrayListAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<ListCustomObjects> datas) {
this.context=context;
    this.datas=datas;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return datas.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return datas.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    //where we check the convertview whethere it is creting first time or not
    if(convertView==null){
        convertView=((LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.sample_data_listview_item,null);
        viewHolder=new ViewHolder();

        viewHolder.image=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.sample_listview_item_imageView);
        viewHolder.name=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.sample_listview_item_name);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    //where we get the views from convertview instead of creating new one.It reduces memory consumption
    else{
        viewHolder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    //here we set the name
    viewHolder.name.setText(datas.get(position).getName());
    //here conversion takes place.
    byte[] imageAsBytes = android.util.Base64.decode(datas.get(position).getPath().getBytes(), android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
    viewHolder.image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length));
    return convertView;
}
//this is used to bind the view as single class
class ViewHolder{
    ImageView image;
    TextView name;
}
}
```

finally create layout as **sample_data_listview_item** for adapter

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/sample_listview_item_imageView" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/sample_listview_item_name" />
  </LinearLayout>
```